# determine the html div element defaullt width and height using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have defined a div within and when I try to determine its width, I get a value -544

I assume unless height and width of the block is not defined its will be zero..

fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/LTgCV/

html

```
<div></div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('div').width())
    alert($('div').height())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is sth different. If you use an empty div it has as default value

```
display: block;
```

so its width is 100% but since it is empty its height is 0px. If you use an empty span element because its default display is

```
display: inline;
```

then its width will be 0px so its height too. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/LTgCV/2/.